# When I try to use list indexing in my if statement, why does it fail?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to index in the statement, it says index out of range. I am trying to scrape stuff from the website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.set.or.th/set/factsheet.do?symbol=TRUE&ssoPageId=3&language=en&country=US')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

list_stuff = list()
for x in soup.findAll('table',{'class':'factsheet'}):
   for tr in x.findAll('tr'):
      stuff=[td for td in tr.stripped_strings]
         if stuff[0] == 'Beta':
            list_stuff.append(stuff[1])
```

The code returns an error saying `list index out of range` and points to the 
`stuff[0]` line in the for loop

Comment: check if `stuff` has any items `len(stuff)>0` or simply `if stuff:`? only access its `[0]`, if it has something in it.

Comment: Probably there are some empty `tr` in your tables. You should guard your code against variable inputs as Patrick mentions (or provide a fallback exception handler)

Answer (score 0):

Add a step to check if the tuple is empty or not.

```
if not not stuff:                     #check if stuff is not empty
    if stuff[0] == 'Beta':
        list_stuff.append(stuff[1])
```

Comment: `if stuff and stuff[0] == 'Beta':`?

Comment: No. Just copy my answer. Stuff is empty so you cannot use stuff[0] since there is no element. Not stuff means it is empty, so not not Stuff will check if it is has some elements in it.

Comment: [Boolean operators in Python are evaluated lazy.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) You should have given it at least a try before dismissing it.

Comment: I tried "if stuff and stuff[0]" but it fails on my testing, so I did not use it